# how can i make objects in main function?

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class distance    //class
{
private:
    int feet;
    float inches;
public:
    distance() :feet(0), inches(0.0)  //constructor
    {}
    distance(int ft, float in) :feet(ft), inches(in)  //constructor
    {}
    void getdist()  //get values
    {
        cout << "Enter feet :";
        cin >> feet;
        cout << "Enter inches :";
        cin >> inches;
    }
    void showdist() //show values
    {
        cout << feet << "-" << inches << endl;
    }
    void adddist(distance, distance); //add distance through objects 
};

void distance::adddist(distance d2, distance d3) //add distance
{
    inches = d2.inches + d3.inches;
    feet = 0;
    if (inches >= 12.0)
    {
        inches -= 12.0;
        feet++;
    }
    feet += d2.feet + d3.feet;
}

int main()
{

}
```

I'm writing a few classes for a homework assignment and I want it to be impossible for my class member functions to be called in main. If they are, I want the program to exit. How would I know when my member functions are being called?

Comment: `I want it to be impossible for my class member functions to be called in main.` Why? What a bizarre requirement. Where *would* you want them to be called from, then? What's the point of the exercise? I strongly suspect we are dealing with an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: `How would I know when my member functions are being called?` Well, when the first statement of the member function executes, you know that function has been called.